# Blocked by CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Why CORS is blocking me when I'm on `HTTP` site but sending request to `HTTPS` despite this configuration?

I've seen that order of placing UseCors is important, so I tried to using it before `UseRouting` and after it, and none of those worked, why?

Page I'm executing request at:
`http://localhost:5000/`

Error

> request for a resource of a different origin blocked: "Same Origin Policy" does not allow to load remote resources from "https://localhost:5000/api/test/" (unsuccessful CORS request).

Difference is `HTTPS` and `HTTP`, but I allowed it?

.NET Core 3.1

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<Context>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Db:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<User>, PasswordHasher<User>>();

    services.AddAuthentication(...).AddJwt(...);

    services.AddCors();

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
    {
        opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Context context)
{
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    app.UseResponseCompression();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBlazorDebugging();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors((x) =>
    {
        x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Startup>("index.html");
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the target side allowing CORS?

Comment: @HenkHolterman this is code of target

Comment: Different ports mean different host/origin. If you want it be reachable on both ports you need to register https AND http handlers. Also make sure you have no exceptiosn. Exceptions clear CORS hears (they clear all headers actually). Also, you have to use `UseCors` before the routing middleware. Middleware is executed in order of registration and if you want protect static files too, then you have to put it before static files middleware too